# how do i make shell ask for confimation for rm -rf command (even sudo)?

Tags: bash, dd, rm

I want to make the command shell to prompt me for confirmation before execution of certain commands like `dd` , `rm -rf` etc.

Comment: I know it's tagged `bash`, but in `zsh` you can get a ten-second wait on `rm -rf *` using `setopt RM_STAR_WAIT` or confirmation using `setopt NO_RM_STAR_SILENT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `safe-rm` will do the work

```
apt install safe-rm
```

Safe-rm is a safety tool intended to prevent the accidental deletion of important files.

```
$ rm -rf /usr
Skipping /usr
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bash script that ask confirmation and then run the desidered program.
Create a file named ask containing:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Are you sure to run $1 command?"
read RES
if [ "$RES" = "Y" ] || [ "$RES" = "y" ] ; then
    echo "Running the command..."
    $@
else
    echo "Command aborted"
fi
```

Copy ask script in /usr/bin/ and set it as executable (or add the script path tho PATH variable):

```
sudo mv path_to_ask_script/ask /usr/bin/ask
cd /usr/bin/
sudo chmod 777 ask
```

Then you have to create an alias in the `~/.bashrc` file:

`alias dd='ask dd'`

Now by typing dd, the ask script should be executed, ask for confirmation and eventually call the dd command.

To extend to other command just add an alias like:

`alias command_name='ask command_name'`
as example:
`alias rm='ask rm'`

For the rm command you can simply create an alias as:
`alias rm='rm -i'`

Script tried and fully working on 16.04 with gnome-terminal

Comment: I think your ask script shouldn't use `$1` but `$@` cause: `ask /bin/cp -Rv /path/to/source /path/to/destination` for `$1` will return only `/bin/cp` and `$@` will return `/bin/cp -Rv /path/to/source /path/to/destination`

Comment: You're right, My bash ability are a bit rusted

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if you really want to use those commands only as sudo:

Go to `/bin`(example, most commands are here) so:

```
cd /bin
# example how to make dd to posibly only for root/sudo (744)
sudo chmod go-x dd
# or even go further restrict the access to the file fully to root (700)
sudo chmod go-rx dd
# to reverse that setting you did do (755)
sudo chmod go+rx dd
```

This removes the executable flags from those commands for group and other.
You can do that with almost all commands and it till tell you have no permission when not using sudo.

Disclaimer: Do not, I mean it, **DO NOT** change permissions on sudo or su you might lock you out of essential stuff and wwould have a hard time fixing.